# How can I adb install an apk to multiple connected devices with -s command?

Tags: android-emulator

I have 2 devices plugged into my development machine.

I was doing Specific command which is given by Android Debug Bridge

```
adb -s serial_number command
```

Suppose I did this:

```
C:\Users\kalpesh>adb devices
List of devices attached
16261522500024  device
16261522500022  device
```

Now I am trying this:

```
C:\Users\kalpesh>adb -s 16261522500024 -s 16261522500022 install Chrome.apk
```

But it is giving this:

```
 adb help                     - show this help message
  adb version                  - show version num

scripting:
  adb wait-for[-<transport>]-<state>
                               - wait for device to be in the given state:
                                 device, recovery, sideload, or bootloader
                                 Transport is: usb, local or any [default=any]
  adb start-server             - ensure that there is a server running
  adb kill-server              - kill the server if it is running
  adb get-state                - prints: offline | bootloader | device
  adb get-serialno             - prints: <serial-number>
  adb get-devpath              - prints: <device-path>
  adb remount                  - remounts the /system, /vendor (if present) and
```

Like some help command